# Linux: What is the order that Debian uses for resoving URL addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm running Linux 10 (Buster) on a Raspberry Pi v4, pretty much a vanilla install.  I wanted the Pi to find a local resource and not try to use its public URL address.  So I put

> 10.0.50.15 [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)

into the `/etc/hosts` file.  The app still seems to be trying to use the public address and fails. I tried pinging the URL and sure enough it returns the public address.  Same result with the HOST command.

Thus, it would seem to me that a DNS search is happening before the HOSTS file is checked?  Is that correct and what can I do to get the HOSTS to function the way I expected?

By the way, the HOSTS file is functioning for local URLs which have no public equivalent.

Comment: What does your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` look like, specifically the line that starts with `hosts:`?  Default for Debian is files first then dns, but it could have changed for your system.

Comment: I suggest using the correct terms. What you have is _not_ a URL. It is a host name or DNS name. // It is important to differentiate clients that do DNS themselves (like `host` or `dig` or whatever) and clients that use the libc `getaddrinfo` and the like. Only the latter are involved with the `hosts` file and `nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Which apps? Note: some apps use directly DNS (and maybe on HTTPS port) instead of using operating system services. Use ping/fping to check the result of operating system preferences

Comment: the /etc/nsswitch.conf file says "hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns".  In the future i will try to use the correct terminology. The app here is postfix.